# Basic asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm new to MVC and all the tutorials I have worked through are very simple. What I want to know is how do you implement an action from a class in another file? For example how do I get an xml reader in a separate class to work in:

```
  public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: you want execute an xml reader from another class? that's not a mvc question but am not sure if this is what you need, can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement the namespace that the class belongs to with a "using" directive at the top of your controller.

```
using WhateverNamespace.XmlReaderNamespace;
```